# What is the original version of "Little Red Riding Hood"?

Tags: european-folklore, fairy-tales

There is a certain version of "Little Red Riding Hood" that some authors claim to be "the original" version. For example in the Sandman comic:

[image: sandman]

Or from the movie [Jin Roh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGXka.jpg).

A quick search on Wikipedia seems to dispell those claims, but I still wish to ask: Is there such a thing as *the* original version of "Little Red Riding Hood", that later becomes the modern version of red riding hood (assuming we could agree on what the modern version is).

Comment: While the author is correct, it's from 1695, so seventeenth century. It's the oldest written account, but not necessarily the original version.